# Finding whether $\sum \frac{1}{(3-(-1)^n)^n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried to check this on WolframAlpha but it said "Standard Computation Time exceeded". I don't know whether it should converge or not.

With alternating series I usually try to find $|a_n|$. In this case I was a bit at a loss so I applied Cauchy's criteria directly to $a_n$:

$$\lim \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{(3-(-1)^n)^n}} = \lim \frac{1}{3-(-1)^n} = 1/2 \lor 1/4$$

That's probably not the correct way to write this so feel free to correct... still either value is $<1$, so the series converges... but does it converge absolutely or conditionally? How to solve this?

Comment: The series has positive terms only so convergence and absolute convergence coincide here.

Comment: You should use the limsup,  not the limit, which doesn't exist in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case since both $\sum \frac 1{2^n}$ and $\sum\frac 1{4^n}$ converge and the initial series is with positive terms you can not only tell the sum is convergent but also effectively calculate the actual value.

Indeed $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{3-(-1)^n}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^{2n}}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{4^{2n+1}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac 14\right)^n+\frac 14\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac 1{16}\right)^n=\frac 43+\frac 14\times\frac {16}{15}=\frac 85$

Comment: So basically if your series is made of two different series that go $a_n+b_n+a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}+...$ and both converges, the whole series converges? Makes sense

Comment: Yes it is necessary that both $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge. For instance using this for $\sum \frac 1{n(n+1)}=\sum \frac 1n-\sum\frac 1{n+1}$ would not be correct although the initial series is ok, the other two are not. WARNING: It is also important that all terms are **positive**, since rearranging positive terms doesn't change the behaviour of a series (I added this precision in my answer, it was missing).

Comment: If I recall right, $\sum \frac 1n-\sum\frac 1{n+1}$ is a telescoping series, correct?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire $\sum (\frac1n-\frac1{n+1})$ is a telescoping series, but that's not what either zwim or you wrote. Can you see the difference?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I see

Answer (score 6):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(3-(-1)^n)^n}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=1.$$
Also, $$\frac{1}{(3-(-1)^n)^n}>0$$
Can you end it now?

$$\frac{1}{(3-(-1)^n)^n}\leq\frac{1}{2^n}$$ it's
$$2^n\leq(3-(-1)^n)^n$$ or
$$2\leq3-(-1)^n$$ or
$$(-1)^n\leq1.$$

Comment: I tried to verify that $a_n \le (\frac{1}{2})^n$ and got $(3+(-1)^n)^n \le 2^n \Leftrightarrow 3-(-1)^n \ge 2 \Leftrightarrow -(-1)^n \ge -1 \Leftrightarrow (-1)^n \le 1$ which is true for all n so it must be true. I did then $a_n/b_n$ ($b_n$ is the geometric series you gave). For n = even number I got $\lim a_n/b_n = 1^n = 1^\infty$. For n = odd number I got $\lim a_n/b_n = 0$ so it converges. What does this mean?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire I added something. See now.

Comment: I saw it, I got that far